# Extracting an array from another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array (contents retrieved from a DB):

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'one' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Billy' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'two' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Mariah' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'three' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'Cindy' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'four' (length=4)
      'name' => string 'Daniel' (length=6)
```

I need to create an array as follows:

```
$info = array('one' => 'Billy', 'two' => 'Mariah', 'three' => 'Cindy', 'four' => 'Daniel');
```

I used a foreach loop to construct the desired array:

```
$info = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $info[] = array($row['number'] => $row['name']);
}
```

and a var_dump() gives me this instead:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'one' => string 'Billy' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'two' => string 'Mariah' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'three' => string 'Cindy' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'four' => string 'Daniel' (length=6)
```

How can I achieve the desired array in PHP? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close.

```
$info = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $info[$row['number']] =$row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP >= 5.5.0 it's much easier:

```
$info = array_column($result, 'name', 'number');
```

Or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)